# urllib python - request timeout, but postman works

Tags: python, urllib

This works as expected via postman.  I saved the output as a curl from postman so you could see the request.

```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://soar.xxx.com/acc_xxx_001/investigation/2009' \
--header 'Authorization: 12345' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"categories": ["chats"]}
'
```

This however is timing out:

```
xsoar_api = 'https://soar.xxx.com/acc_xxx_001/investigation/2009'
req = urllib.request.Request(xsoar_api, method='POST')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('Authorization', '12345')
data = {"categories":["chats"]}
data = json.dumps(data)
data = data.encode()
with urllib.request.urlopen(req, data=data) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
```

ERROR:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Operation timed out>
```

Coming from same machine.....

Answer (score 0):

Ignore, i found solution.

My web address was public facing and my docker container could not hit it...I had to use the server address.